# "Show in folder" in google chrome is not working

Tags: google-chrome

If I download a file in google chrome and select "show in folder" nothing happens. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this occur repeatedly, even after restarting Chrome or Ubuntu? Otherwise, I'm thinking of a crash in `nautilus`. Open a terminal, enter `nautilus -q && nautilus &` and try again.

Comment: Does that work in firefox ? If that does, then it's Chrome problem. If doesn't - might be nautilus problem as Jos suggested.

Comment: @Jos Yes, if I enter `nautilus -q && nautilus &` then it works.

Comment: Allow me to convert this to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nautilus is having trouble showing the downloads folder.
Restart Nautilus as follows:

`nautilus -q && nautilus &`

And all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the Nautilus, or Captain Nemo either, but I found that nothing is displayed when I click "show in folder." But if the "Files" app is pinned to the launch bar, it shakes! Then, if I click on it, voila! it displays the directory containing the download.