# How to prevent opening of a terminal window when a "Show In Folder" action is selected for the downloaded file?

Tags: 14.04, directory

For some reason, when I download something and try to open it via "Show in Folder" option, it is opening a terminal window. Is it possible to prevent that and instead really show it in a folder/new window tab?

I tried something like this after [reading this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657198/show-in-folder-in-google-chrome-is-not-working), but I don't have nautilus installed.

`nautilus -q && nautilus &`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which desktop environment do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by desktop environment. I've encountered this using  Elementary Freya OS. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could reinstall nautilus as below;

```
sudo apt-get  install nautilus
```

Nautilus is default file manager. maybe it removed accidentally.

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on desktop environment installed.

Comment: Thank you, installing nautilus solved the issue. I can't believe the answer is right before my very eyes already! :)